# Увеличенное изображение в Bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap

Если убрать статичные img файлы в слайдере Bootstrap, а вместо них добавить фон  https://jsfiddle.net/Delat/nzy9mhnf/ 
то возникает один недостаток, фон увеличивается становятся видны артефакты. Изображения 1920 на 445px. В чём может быть проблема?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 445px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не вылазит:

```js
var imgs = $('.item img');
imgs.each(function(){
  var item = $(this).closest('.item');
  item.css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')', 
    'background-position': 'center',            
    '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
    'background-size': 'cover', 
  });
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 445px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.elastic.co/assets/bltada7771f270d08f6/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg" alt="" >
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня тоже не вылазит, а увеличивается. В этом то и вопрос был. Если использовать <img> то результат правильный. Если использовать background-size, вот тогда да, появляется проблема http://prntscr.com/hns7x1

Comment: @ikar, ну так это же эффект `background-size: cover;` заполнение изображением по высоте и ширине, потому изображение увеличивается. Используйте изображения одних размеров или пропорций, чтобы влазило в заданную высоту

Comment: хм, что-то я не понимаю. Высота 445px контейнера и фонового изображения. Используется стандартная сетка Bootstrap. Ширина изображения 1920px. Монитор 1280x1024px. http://prntscr.com/hntvo5